# Spreadsheet does not exist in the namespace Telerik.Documents even though nuget Telerik.Documents.Spreadsheet.FormatProviders.Xls is installed

Tags: c#, excel, telerik, .net-standard

Even though I have successfully installed the nuget package `Telerik.Documents.Spreadsheet.FormatProviders.Xls`,
[image]

I am receiving the error : `CS0234: 'Spreadsheet' does not exist in the namespace Telerik.Documents`
[image]

when referencing the package in code.
[image]

I have followed the recommended Telerik setup procedures as outlined by Telerik. I have also been unsuccessful in finding other references online for this issue.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.11.18 and .NET Framework 4.8.4084 .

Since the needed packages are successfully installed and referenced, what else can I do to troubleshoot or to fix the issue?

Comment: Please excuse me, I have recently moved to a new position at a new company and so I no longer have access the code or to Telerik to be able to confirm any answers to this question. If a correct answer can be confirmed with documentation or corroboration I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Telerik.Documents.Spreadsheet.FormatProviders.Xls;
```

use:

```
Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.FormatProviders.Xls;
```

I was facing the same issue and this fixed it. Even though we are not installing the Windows packages but that is how we should reference it.

Comment: Please excuse me, I have recently moved to a new position at a new company and so I no longer have access the code or to Telerik to be able to confirm this answer.

Comment: @TysonGibby if you're no longer in need of support perhaps you should delete the question.

Comment: @Raydot StackOverflow prefers I do not delete the question.